# JScrollPane does not update scrollbar

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jscrollpane

I am trying to create a `JScrollPane` that contains a `JPanel` that will be increasing and decreasing in height. When it becomes larger than the size of the `JScrollPane`, it should create a vertical scroll bar which will allow me to scroll through the entire `JPanel`. However, I am having difficulty achieving this. Yes, I know I am not using `LayoutManager`s. No, I will not be using them, and I need a solution that does not involve their usage.

Here are the two button's `AbstractAction`s that add and subtract from the `JPanel`:

```
class AddACT extends AbstractAction
    {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        info.setSize(420,info.getHeight() + 40);
        info.add(new SubPanel); // Adds another JPanel into the main JPanel (for content input)
        gui.repaint();
        infoS.validate();
      }
    }

class RemoveACT extends AbstractAction
    {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        info.remove(subPanel()); // This would remove the last JPanel added to the main JPanel
        info.setSize(420,info.getHeight() - 40);
        gui.repaint();
        infoS.validate();
      }
```

And here is the code for the main JPanel and the JScrollPane:

```
final JPanel info = new JPanel();
final JScrollPane infoS = new JScrollPane(info, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);  
info.setLayout(null);
info.setSize(420,600);
infoS.setLocation(10,80);
infoS.setSize(420,490);
gui.add(infoS); // gui is the frame's content pane (the overall JPanel)
```

This is the second project I've been trying to learn GUI by doing. I am a complete novice in Swing and am only intermediate in Java. Sorry if I am making a blindingly obvious mistake.

Comment: -1 _Yes, I know I am not using layout managers. No, I will not be using them_ shrugs, it's your time you insist on wasting ;-)

Comment: Is is completely and absolutely necessary to use a layout manager? I was hoping that it wouldn't be necessary, and that, like most things in Java, there were other ways to do it.

Comment: @Thrfoot : A quote from [**Java Docs**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) **"Although it is possible to do without a layout manager, you should use a layout manager if at all possible. A layout manager makes it easier to adjust to look-and-feel-dependent component appearances, to different font sizes, to a container's changing size, and to different locales. Layout managers also can be reused easily by other containers, as well as other programs."**.

Comment: All right, it seems I have no choice. If I were to use a layout manager (probably BoxLayout, to make a vertical list), what would I need to change (beyond the obvious changes like `setSize` to `setPreferredSize`)? I really am not sure as to how JScrollPane interacts with layout managers, and have never really used a layout manager before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Use `LayoutManager`s (+1 to @kleopatra and @GagandeepBali comments)

The absence of `LayoutManager`s only guarantees your GUI's will look very trashy (especially when run on other OSes/builds) and being a Novice you should rather learn the correct way than learn the wrong way and get into bad habits like calling `setSize()` etc.

Have a read on these links to get you started:

- [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

2) See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237678/sticking-components-onto-a-jscrollpane/13237933#13237933) for how to use a `JScrollPane`, it simply adds a `JPanel` with buttons to a `JScrollPane` which in-turn is added to the `JFrame`.

3) Also see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466279/jscrollpane-only-vertical-scroll/13466484#13466484) for how to make the `JScrollPane`  vertically scroll-able only.

4) For more on `JScrollPane`s have a look here: [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html).

5) As for how it interacts with `LayoutManager`, if you do not explicitly set its size via `setPreferredSize(Dimension d)` *the scroll pane computes it based on the preferred size of its nine components (the viewport, and, if present, the two scroll bars, the row and column headers, and the four corners)*

6) On your usage of `validate()`:

- `validate()` is used when new `JComponent`s are added to a visible component
- `revalidate()` is used when `JComponent` is removed/added from a visible component
- `revalidate()` covers `validate()` too

Thus always use this:

```
//add or remove component(s)
revalidate();
repaint();
```

**References:**

- http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/405568/validate-vs-revalidate

Answer (score 2):

`LayoutManager` is not required to solve the problem.  The problem in Thrfoot's example is in these lines:

```
final JScrollPane infoS = new JScrollPane(info, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);  
info.setLayout(null);
info.setSize(420,600);
```

The program appears to recognize there is a need for scroll bars (it would show the scroll bar if your setting was `VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED`), but the actual scrolling does not work (the scroll bar slider is not there).

To fix this, **first** set the *preferred* size of `info`, **then** construct the `infoS`.

Example:

```
info.setPreferredSize(420,600);
final JScrollPane infoS = new JScrollPane(info, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

The idea is to set the preferred size of the `info` panel **before** it is used for the scroll pane. This is the same reason to set the size and location of `infoS` before adding to the `gui`:

```
infoS.setLocation(10,80);
infoS.setSize(420,490);
gui.add(infoS); // gui is the frame's content pane (the overall JPanel)
```